# Set-builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

$A=\{7,14,21,28\}$
is the set-builder notation
$\{x \in \mathbb N:x=7n, n \in \mathbb N \text{ and } 1\le n \le 4\}$
right?

Comment: A={7,14,21,28} (it's not a sequence). It looks correct to me. I would probably use $\land$ instead of comma or descriptive text ("and") though. Not sure if it is necessary with things like $\forall$ etc, guess it depends on the formality level.

Comment: Wellcome to MSE !!

Comment: It is indeed correct but it does carry some redundancies (you've said that $n \in \mathbb{N}$, which already means that $x=7n \in \mathbb{N}$, so saying prior to that that $x \in \mathbb{N}$ is unnecessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

See also The following questions with answers, where more set builder notation very similar examples are discussed: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312526/how-do-i-write-3-6-11-18-27-38-in-set-builder-notation?rq=1), [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78510/how-do-i-write-this-in-set-builder-notation?rq=1) and [Especially This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739152/writing-in-set-builder-notation?rq=1).